# FaceBook Auth and signed request

Tags: facebook, flash, authentication, facebook-graph-api, oauth

on the client side I am using the flash API to sign in and auth the client

```
Facebook.init(MyFaceBooyKey, faceBookInit);
```

Then face book sends back to the client a Signed Request and other stuff.

I the client then sends this signed request to my server.

On my server I process the Signed Request and out pops a FaceBook User id (UID)

So now I am assuming that:

The client who sent the valid signed request is the owner of the Face book UID contained inside it, the client must know the password for that UID, and they are loged into facebook ?

Is this system safe ?

how can i safely use user client side facebook auth to then autho in to a second server, eg a sepreak facebook game server.

How can I make suer that the signed reques has not been coped in transit on the web,
and then sent to me by a thirs party, who now logs on to my server under a Uiffrent UID

How to all theas flash based facebook games auth the users ?

also I note that the same book auth vias the Desktop application dose not send a signed reques ?  so how to do the auth to my server in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

All of the auth flows with facebook use SLL (https) and so the data you send/get is secured.
The same goes for all of the graph api requests, if you try to make an api request in http while including an access token you'll get this response:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "You must use https:// when passing an access token",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1
   }
}
```

If you send the signed request and/or the access token to your server then you should do it by https as well and that way that communication will also be secured.

The client (and I assume you meany the flash client) is not the "owner" of the access token/signed request, your app is the "owner".

If you need the access token on the server side I suggest that you use the [Server-Side Auth flow](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) to get it.
If you then need the access token on the client side then you can use a client side auth, since the user already authorized the app and authenticated for sure (through the server side flow) the client side process should be completely invisible for the user, and at the end of it you'll have an access token on the client side as well (a different one than on the server).

Comment: ok, thanks for that,  I all most forgot about all this facebook app dev cus I picked up a "real job" for a bit.  what you are saying sounds good.  So I should to a server side auth with, php, making sure the users is loged in and there facebook ID is really theres.  and then do a client side auth which should be invisiable, so the flash client can wright on there wall.    I will have to check the permition requests are the same ?

Comment: That's correct. In the client side use the javascript sdk with 'FB.login' and include the same permissions you ask on the server side, you should get a client side token "silently".

Answer (score 0):

```
 "message": "You must use https:// when passing an access token",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1
   }
} "message": "You must use https:// when passing an access token",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1
   }
} "message": "You must use https:// when passing an access token",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1
   }
}
```